# How to Karma test Restangular http call using httpbackend to test both success and error cases?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I am testing an angular service using karma/jasmine and one of my service functions is as follows. I need to get coverage to 100%, but can't seem to figure out how to test both success and error cases..

```
function getAccount(accountId) {
   var defer = $q.defer(), myService;
   myService = Restangular.all('Some/Url/Path');
   myService.get('', {}, {
     'header-info': 'bla'
   })
   .then(function onSuccess(response) {
      defer.resolve(response);
   }, function onError() {
      someMethodCall();
   });
   return defer.promise;
}
```

In my corresponding .spec test file, I have:

```
it('should succeed in getting account', function() {
   httpBackend.whenGET('Some/Url/Path').respond(200, mockResponse);
   var promise = myServices.getAccount('account123');
   promise.then(function(response) {
     expect(response).toEqual(mockResponse);
});

it('should error out in getting account', function() {
   httpBackend.whenGET('Some/Url/Path').respond(500, '');
   var promise = myServices.getAccount('account123');
   promise.then(function() {
     expect(someMethodCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Right now, both cases "pass", but I'm not getting the branch coverage for the onError case. Something seems fishy about the onSuccess case passing too.

Basically I am asking what is the correct syntax and way of writing the test cases such that I can hit both success and on error cases when I make a 200 and a 500 call to my API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't have any calls to `$http` in your service, I would recommend mocking `Restangular` instead of using `httpBackend`. This way your test doesn't have to know anything about the implementation details of `Restangular`, other than what it returns, just like your service.

Mock example:

```
var Restangular = {
  all: function() {
    return {
      get: function() {
        restangularDeferred = $q.defer();
        return restangularDeferred.promise;
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Now you can easily either resolve or reject `restangularDeferred` depending on what you want to test.

Set up your module to use the mock:

```
module('myApp', function($provide) {

  $provide.value('Restangular', Restangular);
});
```

Example test of success case:

```
it('success', function() {

  // If you want you can still spy on the mock
  spyOn(Restangular, 'all').and.callThrough();

  var mockResponse = {};

  var promise = myServices.getAccount('account123');

  promise.then(function(response) {

    expect(response).toEqual(mockResponse);
    expect(Restangular.all).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Some/Url/Path');
  });

  restangularDeferred.resolve(mockResponse);

  // Trigger the digest loop and resolution of promise callbacks
  $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

Example test of error case:

```
it('error', function() {

  spyOn(anotherService, 'someMethodCall');

  var mockResponse = {};

  myServices.getAccount('acount123');

  restangularDeferred.reject(mockResponse);

  $rootScope.$digest();

  expect(anotherService.someMethodCall).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

*Note that I moved `someMethodCall` into `anotherService` in the example.*

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/4JprZPvbN0bYSXFobgmu?p=preview

Comment: Thank you!! Works perfectly